# How to use GWT's editor framework?

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm trying to learn how to use Google's Web Toolkit (GWT) [editor framework.](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html) I haven't been able to understand how I can use it through the documentation. The examples I've found online were not helpful for me to begin with. I would like to ask if someone can provide a simple working example.

Comment: What do you want to do? What have you tried? How did it not work?

Comment: I want to use the framework so that a user can click within a list of objects edit an object in a dialog box and then save it. I haven't been able to compile and run a simple example yet. Also I am not using UiBinder at the moment.

Comment: Have you, by any chance, read http://blog.ltgt.net/gwt-21-editors/ ? Specifically look at the before/after example in the conclusion and fill the holes (and remove UiBinder if you don't use it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book [GWT in Action, second edition](https://www.manning.com/books/gwt-in-action-second-edition) has a chapter about the `EditorFramework`.

The sample code is free to download:
[GWTInActionSamples](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/9/7cb4945-a92f-43d7-b2cc-3ab57e8672c2/gwtinaction2.zip)

You should find working examples in chapter 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at the following sites for further reference, good examples to get your hands dirty with! Might not be a full blown examples, but definitely a good read to understand the concepts!

- http://cancerberonia.blogspot.in/2011/12/gwt-editor-framework-100-java-example.html
- https://github.com/marcojakob/doxblox-server/wiki/GWT-Editor-Framework